# wiring generic interface type to different implementations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ninject-2

I'm trying to get this working, and I can't find a good solution. I know that StructureMap can do this, but I'm stuck with Ninject.

What I have:

```
public interface IFormHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T form);
}
```

And I want to implement multiple classes like this one:

```
public class RegioDeleteModelFormHandler:IFormHandler<RegioDeleteModel>
{
    public void Handle(RegioDeleteModel form)
    {
    //implement method here
    }
}
```

or this one:

```
public class RegioUpdateModelFormHandler:IFormHandler<RegioUpdateModel>
{
    public void Handle(RegioUpdateModelform)
    {
    //implement method here
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in the code, I would like to be able to call something like this:

```
var handler = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IFormHandler<T>>();
```

to get the correct IFormhandler back.

Is there a way to do this? If Ninject cannot do this, is there a workaround? Currently, I only have the base nuGet Package for Ninject. Is there something I can use from one of the related packages?

For completeness sake, here is my DependencyResolverclass:

public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver {
    private IKernel kernel;

```
public NinjectDependencyResolver() {
    kernel = new StandardKernel();
    AddBindings();
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
    return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
}

public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {
    return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
}

public IBindingToSyntax<T> Bind<T>() {
    return kernel.Bind<T>();
}

public IKernel Kernel {
    get { return kernel; }
}

private void AddBindings() {
    Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
}
```

}

thanks in advance!

**EDIT my edit**: Maybe I should add that I tried this in the AddBindings method above and that it works, but that's a lot of code, if I have to do it for all possible IFormHandlers:

```
Bind<IFormHandler<RegioDeleteModel>>().To<RegioDeleteModelFormHandler>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conventions: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/What-is-configuration-by-convention